# JSONPath How to read an invalid key from JSON

Tags: jsonpath

```json
{
    "inputs":{
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2
    }
}
```

As a json above, I want to read a key not exist in the json, my code is

```java
Configuration conf = Configuration
        .builder()
        .jsonProvider(new JsonSmartJsonProvider())
        .options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS)
        .build();
DocumentContext parse = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(capturedArgument.getContext());
Object params = JsonPath.read(parse, "$.params");
```

but it still throw exception：com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['params'] in path $ but found 'com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.

I hope the params return null。